# How to create lines in xml

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I was wondering how to create straight lines in xml.

Comment: How to create straight lines in xml...? Do you mean how to I store geometric points that can be used to make a line in XML?

Answer (score 27):

Use this to display a single white line with xml

```
<View android:layout_width="1dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for something like this...

[Vertical line using XML drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658772/android-vertical-line-xml)