# Change the color of the cursor of an EditText in Android 3.0

Tags: android, android-edittext, text-cursor

I have to have an EditText in my application with a white background. I did this in my theme.xml file

```
<style name="myEditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
  <item name="android:background">#ffffffff</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">#ff000000</item>
</style>
```

The problem now is that the cursor is still white and therefore not visible.
I did some googling and found this question here on StackOverflow:
[Set EditText cursor color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238450/set-edittext-cursor-color)

The way it's done there is the `android:textCursorDrawable` key. But this key does seem to be only available with a 3.2 target. But our clients wants a 3.0 target and I could not find any other solution...

**Is there any way i can change the color of the blinking cursor with 3.0 as the target?**

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238450/set-edittext-cursor-color

Please check upper link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer :)

I've set the Theme's editText style to:

```
<item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/myEditText</item>
```

Then I've used the following drawable to set the cursor:

```
<style name="myEditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.EditText"> 
<item name="android:background">@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal</item> 
<item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@android:drawable/my_cursor_drawable</item> 
<item name="android:height">40sp</item> </style>
```

**android:textCursorDrawable** is the key here.

And also refer this one 
[Vertical line using XML drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658772/android-vertical-line-xml)

Comment: Sorry, you probably didn't read the question. `testCursorDrawable` is unavailable in android 3.0

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to change the cursor color in my app which targeted API 8. I've found out that `TextView` uses `textColor` property as the cursor color. Here's a part of `onDraw()` defined in `TextView` API 8:

```
    int color = mCurTextColor;

    if (mLayout == null) {
        assumeLayout();
    }

    Layout layout = mLayout;
    int cursorcolor = color;
```

The `cursorcolor` is then used to constract an android.graphics.Path object representing the color.

If you need to change this behaviour, you're up to quite a task, you'll have to implement your own `TextView`.