# How to change the color of the EditText cursor drag and text select buttons?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'd like to change the color of the (blue) buttons that are used to position the cursor inside an EditText. Any ideas how this can be done?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your support. What I was looking for is answered at this SO question:
[How to change color / appearance of EditText select handle / anchor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133926/android-change-color-appearance-of-edittext-select-handle-anchor)

Answer (score 1):

```
<item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/myEditText</item>

<style name="myEditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.EditText">    
<item name="android:background">@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal</item>     
<item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@android:drawable/my_cursor_drawable</item>     
<item name="android:height">40sp</item> </style>
```

should work...

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set the `text_select_handle`drawable (here: [Other Drawables Resources](http://androiddrawables.com/Other.html) at the bottom) to your style as @user2383106 said (see also: [Change the color of the cursor of an EditText in Android 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9518771/2668136)).

Hope this helps.