# create vertical gradient in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create vertical gradient separator in android

I am `able to create for horizontal separator` but `in vertical gradient nothing appears`

*code for horizontal*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
       <gradient       
                android:startColor="#DEDEDE"
                android:centerColor="#F52578"
                android:endColor=  "#DEDEDE"
      /> 
</shape>
```

this is how i use in my project

```
  <View 
            android:background="@drawable/divider_gradient"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1.0px"

     />
```

> i tried layout_width="1dp" and layout_height="fill_parent" for
>   vertical separator but nothing appears

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658772/android-vertical-line-xml

Comment: @Waqas the question that you have suggested is for solid line and what i am asking is a gradient

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use

```
android:angle="270"
```

as another attribute in your gradient

to get you start color - center color - end color as **Top  to Bottom**

Comment: garg i tried                 `android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
         android:centerColor="#F52578"
         android:endColor=  "#FFFFFF"
         android:angle="270" ` but its not working

Comment: the gradient you mentioned is correct,, how are you using it in the view... `            android:layout_height="1.0px"` not this right... that would make the height 1 px..and you won't see gradient... What is the current color of the view visible..?

Comment: These are the attributes of view `android:background="@drawable/divider_gradient"
      android:layout_width="1dp"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

Comment: is view showing up at all..? try changing android:background="#FFF", and notice if the view is visible at all of complete white background.. if yes then you can change that to gradient.. otherwise problem is in you `view` position and size...

Comment: yes,  view is visible if i remove the gradient and pass the solid color , but when i change it to gradient it disappears

Comment: quite strange!!  just for debugging can you try to put `<solid android:color="#FFF"/>` and removing gradient at all from `divider_gradient` to see if the gradient is actually being applied on the view..

Comment: Yes a solid like appears , after i replace the gradient tag with a solid tag , n yes this seems pretty strange

Comment: just for info..did you get it corrected?? and what was the defect/reason earlier?

Comment: gard i tried your code only actually gradient wasn't visible in emulator , but was showing in a real device , so +1 for showing your interest

Comment: Thanks it help,really easy answer

Answer (score 1):

Make use of Angle attribute to achieve gradient in wanted direction. More at  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Comment: what angle did u try working with ?? Also try changing that width to something like 4dp for trials first instead of 1.0px, and I would suggest u to use 1dp instead of 1px always