# Android padding left for a text in a TextView which contains an image on left and text on right

Tags: android, user-interface

I have a TextView which contains an image on the left side and text on the right side:

[image]

I would like to create a space between the vertical line and the text.

This is my code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/locationDetailsTitleTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/map_activity_location_details_dialog_title"
    android:textColor="@color/actionbar_title_color"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/balloon_line" />
```

How can I do this?

**UPDATE**

This is the `Drawable` I use in `balloon_line`:

[image]

Comment: just wondering, what `Drawable` did u use for your balloon_line?

Comment: That `Drawable`is pretty simple. It is a transparent square with the right margin representing the blue line you see next to the text. I will left you an update with the `Drawable`.

Comment: thanks. I ended up using a `<View></View>` with a colored background, since I didn't want to deal with a tiny image :) (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2659038/1161743)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried using `android:drawablePadding`?

**Example:** Adding a 5dp padding between the text and the left-side drawable

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/locationDetailsTitleTextView"
    ...
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/balloon_line" 
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I want!

Answer (score 2):

use this tag in your textview `android:drawablePadding="5dp"`