# How build a vertical divider

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have the following [divider](https://github.com/tato469/Android/raw/master/dividers/images/cool_divider.jpg) and I wanted do the same effect but in vertical. How could I do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#0fffffff"
                android:centerColor="#ff696969"
                android:endColor="#0fffffff"
                android:angle="90"></gradient>
            <size android:height="2dp"></size>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff"></solid>
            <size android:height="1dp"></size>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I get the [**solution**](https://github.com/tato469/Android/tree/master/dividers) with the help of Celta, I didnt use the divider xml and build my own lLinearLayout:

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
            <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="#ff696969"></View>
                            <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="#ffffff"></View>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check and try solutions from [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658772/android-vertical-line-xml).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use a `View`

Horizontal:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
```

Vertical:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
```

Comment: It+s a View, you have to align it with a android:layout_alignParentTop="true" or other like this one

Comment: But this dont show the same effect but in vertical, I have in top a gray bar and in bootom white bar, and I want at the left the gray bar and right white bar. Im checking with rotate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658772/android-vertical-line-xml

Comment: use the xml vertical i give you with android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" or
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"