# Horizontal line between two equal width TextViews

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview

I have a LinearLayout that fills the whole screen horizontally. It has two TextViews with `layout_weight` of 1. Now I want to add a one dp wide line seperating these two elements. How do I add, for example, a View element with width of one dp?

This one could be used as the View.

[Vertical line using XML drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658772/android-vertical-line-xml)

Here's my layout for the relevant part.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionSave"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Save" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionCancel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Cancel" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is the problem with the answer given in the link?

Comment: @Naddy Hey, my bad.. check my comment on Manishika's answer.

Comment: Is the problem solved now?

Comment: @Naddy Yes, waiting for being able to mark Manishika's answer correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `View` with `width` 1dp between the two `TextViews`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionSave"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Save" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#123456" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionCancel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Cancel" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. That was simple. My problem was that Eclipse was inserting layout_weight attribute for the View too, so each one of them took 33 % of the width. I didn't notice that. Thanks!