# How to add this Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

How to add this Layout to my CardView ?

I want to have a TextView, a divider and another TextView like in the "after" picture.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/post_year"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/post_title"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="My First Post" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: post your layout...

Comment: What you posted doesn't contain a `CardView`. Is that really your layout?

Comment: I include this layout in the CardView.... The CardView is not interesting....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `android:orientation` to horizontal. For the divider, the answer is in this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2659038/433804

```
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#FF0000FF" />
```

Answer (score 2):

@Ajay Shrestha solution works perfectly, just adding another possible solution.
If you do not want to fix the height of `cardview` as there can be some text in multiple lines, then follow below code. Otherwise, @Ajay Shrestha solution is much simpler. Just remove the padding of the `Textviews` and fix the height of `CardView`

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:contentPadding="10dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/post_year"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="1" 
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorLightGray"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/post_year"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/post_title"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/post_year"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/post_title"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="My First Post"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/line"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do Like this

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="4" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:background="@color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Okay I am here" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```